# Accessing method on root within components binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have here some sample code for knockoutjs components in which I have a problem in need of solving:

```html
<template id="item-list-tmpl">
   <ul data-bind="foreach: MyList">
      <li>
         <span data-bind="text: $data.DisplayText"></span>
         <span data-bind="text: $root.DeleteItem"></span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</template>
```

```js
ko.components.register('item-list', {
    template: $("#item-list-tmpl").html(),
    viewModel: function (params) {
        self.MyList = params.MyList; // object inside this list { DisplayText: "Sample Text" }
    }
});
```

I want to know how I can access the `Delete` function on my root view model

Here's how I'm using the component:

```html
<div data-bind='component:{
            name: "item-list"
            params: { 
               MyList: myVM.MyList 
            }
       }'></div>
```

Here is my main view model code structure where `MyList` resides:

```
function MainVM(){
   var self = this;

   self.MyList = ko.observableArray([{ DisplayText: "Sample Text" }]);
   self.Delete = function(value){
       self.MyList.remove(value);
   };
}
```

My problem here is that I can't seem to access the `Delete` function from my main view model inside the list elements. Does anyone here have an idea of what was happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you don't *want* to access `Delete` on the *root* object, because I don't think it's there. Instead, it seems it'll be on the root's `myVM` property.

Because you do `MyList: myVM.MyList` you effectively skip one layer of context, so `myVM` is never really the context, and you'll always have to refer to it again when you access the root. So something like `$root.myVM.Delete` should work. Alternatively you can get there through the `$parents[]` hierarchy:

```js
ko.components.register('item-list', {
    template: $("#item-list-tmpl").html(),
    viewModel: function (params) {
        self.MyList = params.MyList; // object inside this list { DisplayText: "Sample Text" }
    }
});

function MainVM(){
   var self = this;
   self.MyList = ko.observableArray([{ DisplayText: "Sample Text" }]);
   self.Delete = function(value){ console.log(value);
       self.MyList.remove(value);
   };
}

ko.applyBindings({myVM: new MainVM()});
```

```css
pre { background: white; padding: 10px; color: #333; font: 11px consolas; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<template id="item-list-tmpl">
   <ul data-bind="foreach: MyList">
      <li>
         <span data-bind="text: $data.DisplayText"></span>
         <button data-bind="click: $root.myVM.Delete">$root.myVM.Delete</button>
         <button data-bind="click: $parents[1].myVM.Delete">$parents[1].myVM.Delete</button>
      </li>
   </ul>
</template>

<div data-bind='component: { 
  name: "item-list",   
  params: { MyList: myVM.MyList } 
}'></div>

<hr>Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```